# How can I redirect one file in a subdomain to a new URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been using `.htaccess` to redirect URL's on an old website to a sub domain containing the old site files.  For example, my `.htaccess` file is full of rules like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^some-file.html$ http://subdomain.domain.com/some-file.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

However, there is one file in the subdirectory that I would like to point to a different URL.  How can I reverse this for one file, and have `http://subdomain.domain.com` 301 redirect to `http://www.domain.com/some/directory/`?

**Edit:** This is what I currently have in my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(somefile.html)/?$ http://www.domain.com/some/directory/ [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(some-file.html)/?$ http://www.domain.com/some/directory/ [L,R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory of `subdomain.domain.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(some-file|somefile)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/some/directory/ [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you have verified that rule is working fine just change `R=302` to `R=301`.

This will redirect `some-file.html` or `` `somefile.html `` to redirect to `www.domain.com/some/directory/`

Comment: Thanks! I should have made this clear in my initial post, but what if the old file is `some-file.html` and I want it to direct to `www.domain.com/some/directory/` ?  Sorry for not clarifying, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the above edit, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I have added my current `.htaccess` to the original.

Comment: I have combined both of your rules into one. Make sure above .htaccess is in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `subdomain.domain.com`. Also make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and there is no other conflicting URL rewriting happening. I will need to sign off now, will check again in few hours.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I will let you know if this works!